# I am trying to use UseFileServer in Asp.Net Core and it's not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, static-files

I have installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles (NuGet package) and below is the pertinent startup code. I have an index.html file both in the root directory and in a folder called static.

All in all, it seems pretty straightforward... not sure why I'm having trouble.

In debug mode on my localhost... I get:

https://localhost:44331 (404)

https://localhost:44331/index.html (404)

https://localhost:44331/static (404)

https://localhost:44331/static/index.html (200)

https://localhost:44331/api/values (200)

When I publish to an azure web app server, none of the above urls works except:

https://myserver.com/api/values (200)

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }



    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseFileServer();
    }
```

[image]

**Update per the answer (this worked)**

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to be served correctly, your file should be in `wwwroot` folder.

If in `wwwroot` you will put your `index.html`, then you can access it by `htts://localhost:44331/index.html`.